# Is it fine to use Chi-squared test with parameters estimated from the same dataset?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I'm studying the Kolmogorov-Smirnov and Chi-squared tests.

From [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/107815/132503),

> On the other hand the **chi-squared** statistic does give useful shortcuts if you are trying to model the parameters that describe a set of data and the uncertainties on those parameters. The **K-S test** should not really be used if there are adjustable parameters which are being optimised to fit the data.

From [this article](https://asaip.psu.edu/Articles/beware-the-kolmogorov-smirnov-test/),

> **K-S test** probabilities are wrong if the model was derived from the dataset.

In [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92627/how-to-use-the-chi-squared-test-to-determine-if-data-follow-the-poisson-distribu), the author uses the parameter estimated from the dataset itself to do the **Chi-squared** test on the same dataset.

As such, I got that it's problematic to use **K-S test** with parameters optimized to fit the data.

---

**My questions:** Is it fine to use **Chi-squared** test with parameters estimated from the data itself?

Comment: It depends on *which* chi-squared test you use and how you apply it.  For a fairly general answer that covers these issues, please see the duplicate thread.