# Whether to Use Continuity Correction When Conducting a Test of Equality of 2 Proportions

Tags: r

I am using the command in R to conduct a test of equality of two proportions:

```
prop.test(x=c(226,181), n=c(365,335), correct=F)
```

The p-value varies slightly if I turn on the `correct=T`. Can anyone tell me that whether I should use correction in this case?

Comment: `correct=TRUE` is for considering Yates' continuity correction.

Comment: Yes, I know. But should I consider continuity correction in this particular case? I am thinking that the n is large so the answer is no...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, Yates showed that the use of Pearson’s chi-squared has the implication of p–values which underestimate the true p–values based on the binomial distribution, but that you already know. Actually, statisticians tend to disagree about whether to use it: some statisticians argue that expected frequency lower that ***five*** should imply the use of that correction, while others use ***ten*** as that value, while others make the case that Yates' Correction should be used in every chi-squared tests with contingency tables 2 X 2.

Comment: @Sheldon: I have just run your code and edited the question. The differences in the p-values aren't that small. I should be more conservative in your case and use the Yates' correction stating, nevertheless, the reason of your option.