# How do I choose which confident interval for proportion difference to use in SAS?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, proportion, sas

In SAS, there are different CIs for proportion difference ($\pi_1-\pi_2$) to choose?

1.Continuity-corrected Wald CIs based on  normal approximation

2.exact method

3.Miettinen-Nurminen CIs based on score test

4.Newcombe hybrid score CIs based on Wilson score CIs for binominal proportion

Comment: I imagine that each style of CI has somewhat different properties and that each has people who think it is best. Maybe you can google each style and see which seems best for your application. // You might start by looking to see which style(s) may be useful in your currect application. In R, if $\hat\pi_1 = 10/100 = 0.100, \hat\pi_2 = 20/150 = 0.133,$ then code `prop.test(c(10, 20), c(100, 150))$conf.int` returns 95% CI $(-0.1218,\, 0.0551).$ The null hypothesis $H_0: \pi_1 = \pi_2$ is not rejected against the two-sided alternative, so it is reasonable that the CI includes $0.$

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error 
messages, code or packages, etc.) are generally off topic 
here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: Does https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123609/exact-two-sample-proportions-binomial-test-in-r-and-some-strange-p-values answer your question?

Comment: I found this [paper](https://lexjansen.com/wuss/2016/127_Final_Paper_PDF.pdf) FYI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of intervals out there for the binomial proportion. [This paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-16/issue-2/Interval-Estimation-for-a-Binomial-Proportion/10.1214/ss/1009213286.full) does a fairly good job of comparing some of them on coverage and length (typically, you want coverage closest to nominal with smallest length.  Shorter intervals are higher precision so close to nominal coverage and short length is desirable).

The paper linked does not compare those exactly, but should be sufficient to get you started.